# Dynamically hide ALV columns by data type

Tags: abap, alv

Background: I'm using the `cl_salv_table` class to generate and modify an ALV. This ALV displays a table of type `zpm_et_qual_notif_s`, where every even number row is a delimiter field of type `CHAR` length `1` with names `DELIM1`, `DELIM2`...etc. Since there's no reason to have delimiter columns displayed in the ALV, I'd like to remove them.

Note: I left "ABAP Dictionary/Internal Structure" generic in the title because whether or not I determine the column count from the ABAP Dictionary structure or the internal table I define from it matters not to me.

---

The easy solution for me would be to have these 15 statements, as there are currently 15 delimiter fields:

```
lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'DELIM1' )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'DELIM2' )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'DELIM3' )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'DELIM4' )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'DELIM5' )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
...
```

The problem with this is that if new fields are added to the table, my program would also have to be updated. For this reason, and that this approach requires many almost duplicate lines, I find this to be a sloppy solution.

---

What I believe to be a cleaner solution is to dynamically set the visibility of all of the delimiter columns in a manner like so:

```
" Dynamically hide delimiter columns
DATA lv_idx TYPE syst_index VALUE 1.
WHILE lv_idx < 16. " Number of delimiters
    lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( |DELIM{ lv_idx }| )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
    lv_idx = lv_idx + 1.
ENDWHILE.
```

This is nice because it's a simple solution and introduces minimal overhead. However, I still have the problem of having to hard code the number of delimiter columns. An ideal solution would let me do this:

```
" Dynamically hide delimiter columns
DATA lv_idx TYPE syst_index VALUE 1.
WHILE lv_idx < ( columns( 'ZPM_ET_QUAL_NOTIF_S' ) / 2 ). " Number of delimiters
    lv_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( |DELIM{ lv_idx }| )->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
    lv_idx = lv_idx + 1.
ENDWHILE.
```

...but of course, that isn't a thing.

How may I dynamically get the column count of my internal table, or of the ABAP Dictionary structure that it's based upon? Surely there's *some* dynamic solution to this. Trying to solve this problem myself led me to toying around with `cl_abap_structdescr` and `cl_abap_tabledescr`, but nothing substantial came of it. If my entire approach is bad, I'm comfortable with changing it in order to follow good practice.

Comment: are you trying to upload data from a file to fill this table?

Comment: @jhamu no, the input data was coming from a customer database table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would tag these columns with `set_technical` to prevent them from being displayed entirely. `set_visible( abap_false )` only hides them from the current/initial display, but the user can select to show these columns which might be confusing.

Then, I would probably try to distinguish these columns by their data element rather than their position. (Pseudo-)code, untested:

```
DATA(columns) = my_alv->get_columns( ).
DATA(column_list) = columns->get( ).
LOOP AT column_list ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<column>).
  IF <column>-r_column->get_ddic_rollname( ) = 'Z_IRRELEVANT_DELIMITER'.
    <column>-r_column->set_technical( ).
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Many great ideas here - thank you. I've revised my code to use `set_technical( )`, and I've changed the data types of the delimiter fields to type `DELIM` instead of `CHAR` of length `1` (I should have done this in the first place). I'm trying to figure out how to actually loop over the columns, since `my_alv->get_columns( )` returns an object of `TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE`, not a table.

Comment: The original code seemed to be missing a call to `GET( )`, this will get the table from `TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE`

Comment: Yup - untested, as I wrote :-) Thanks for the head-up, I've added the call.

Comment: Thank you, @vwegert and @Gert-Beukema! This is the clean, simple, dynamic solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet determines the number of columns in the active version of a data dictionary structure or table.

```
  SELECT COUNT( * ) INTO @DATA(num_cols)
                    FROM dd03l
                   WHERE tabname EQ @p_struct
                     AND as4local EQ 'A'. " Active
```

Other solutions can be made using the [RTTS framework](http://help-legacy.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENRTTI.htm), or using `ASSIGN COMPONENT`.

Comment: I would recommend against accessing the repository/dictionary tables directly if an API exists - in this case, multiple alternatives exist. Also (though irrelevant for this particular question), this will fail if the display is not based on a DDIC structure, but a type local to the program.