# Dynamically Modify Internal Table Values by Data Type

Tags: abap

This is a similar question to [the one I posted last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698675/dynamically-hide-alv-columns-by-data-type).

I have an internal table based off of a dictionary structure with a format similar to the following:

```
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+-----+
| column1 | delim1 | column3 | delim2 | column5 | delim3 | ... |
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+-----+
| value1  | |      | value 1 | |      | value 1 | |      | ... |
| value2  | |      | value 2 | |      | value 2 | |      | ... |
| value3  | |      | value 3 | |      | value 3 | |      | ... |
+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+-----+
```

The `delim*` columns are all of type `delim`, and the typing of the non-delimiter columns are irrelevant (assuming none of them are also type `delim`).

The data in this table is obtained in a single statement:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE <internal_table_name>.
```

Thus, I have a completely full table except for the delimiter values, which are determined by user input on the selection screen (that is, we cannot rely on them always being `,`, or any other common delimiter).

---

**I'd like to find a way to dynamically set all of the values of type `delim` to some input for every row.**

---

Obviously I could just hardcode the delimiter names and loop over the table setting all of them, but that's not dynamic. Unfortunately I can't bank on [a simple API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702961/975624).

What I've tried (this doesn't work, and it's such a bad technique that I felt dirty just writing it):

```
DATA lt_fields TYPE TABLE OF rollname.
SELECT fieldname FROM dd03l
           INTO TABLE lt_fields
                WHERE tabname  = '<table_name>'
                  AND as4local = 'A'
                  AND rollname = 'DELIM'.
LOOP AT lt_output ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs>).
  LOOP AT lt_fields ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs2>).
    <fs>-<fs2> = '|'.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Once again, I'm not set in my ways and would switch to another approach altogether if I believe it's better.

Comment: Maybe get the tables structure via `cl_abap_tabledescr=>describe_by_data( .. )` and loop over those fields? In this way you have access to the fieldname (compatible to `ASSIGN COMPONENT`) and the component type.

Comment: I resisted asking the last time, but - why on earth do you insist on keeping possibly billions of delimiters in memory all the time? Who would want an ALV grid full of delimiters that are then set to technical to prevent being shown? If you need a delimiter for export, why not add it during the export routine?

Comment: @vwegert oh, ask away. Why do you assume I insist? I did say I was open to better approaches, did I not? This is for an extract program, and a radio button set will allow the user to choose how they want the output (ALV, local .csv download, or FTP). I won't waste time/memory inputting the delimiters unless it's going to be outputted in .csv format. Could you expound on the export routine you're talking about? I am currently using the `GUI_DOWNLOAD` function module, which, as far as I can tell, takes no custom delimiter input, hence the extra fields.

Comment: The various built-in download functions don't quote delimiters either, especially not if they are user-selectable. You might end up with a broken file through a combination of a bad delimiter choice by the user and some text field that contains that delimiter. Try to lock down the export format as much as possibly, then implement that. Chances are complex options are neither understood nor used by the users anyway.

Comment: @vwegert you're right, it's not exactly user-safe and could cause a problem. However, ignoring that, assuming `|` is a "safe" delimiter (it is in this situation), I'm still unsure of a proper way to solve this.

Comment: This has XY problem written all over it. Aren't you basically asking "*How can I export an itab to CSV with a user-defined delimiter?*" You are massively overcomplicating this.

Comment: @Lilienthal for sure. The glory in SO is that you ought to show what you've attempted and vwegert is going to ask what I'm actually trying to accomplish anyway, so I might as well start with it. I tried to make it clear that I'm open to a better solution to the whole problem. I tried my best to not write a post saying "Here's my problem. Write my code" or ask an ambiguous question with multiple opinionated possible answers.

Comment: @gkubed That's fine. But I'd have expected you to get similar feedback on your earlier question as it suffers the same problem: you're treating data in a particular output format (CSV) as data of another (an itab). If you want to show your data: do it in an ALV and use the itab. If you want to download to CSV convert it on-the-fly using the specified delimiter. There is absolutely no reason to ever convert a CSV to a table while preserving the delimiters as columns. The very nature of the format means that the delimiters have no content value.

Comment: @Lilienthal Gotcha. So - flatten the table while inserting the delimiter (convert to table of strings), and output with `GUI_DOWNLOAD` that way? That does seem like a more obvious approach.

Comment: @gkubed Yep. You have two output modes: screen (ALV) and file (CSV). Both should operate from the basic data container which is your itab in this case. As an example if you would take a different object as data source, like a CDS view or even the database table itself, you wouldn't insert delimiters there any more than you would here. The pseudocode algorithm for flattening a table and creating a CSV is trivial but you can find some references on SCN. They mention FM `SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT` as well but I haven't checked if that really works.

Comment: I was able to remove the delimiter columns and flatten the internal table, using the new(ish) ABAP concatenation to insert the user-defined delimiters and download with `GUI_DOWNLOAD`. Once the delimiter fields were gone, modifying with respect to data type was no longer necessary. This also let me ditch the ALV technical fields change I made as per my last question, which I think everyone should be happy with (although I'm glad I understand it now)! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still believe you're barking up the wrong tree with the entire approach, You have been pointed [in the right direction](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/fc/eb3923358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) both here and in the previous question

```
ASSIGN COMPONENT <fs2> OF STRUCTURE <fs> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs3>). " might just as well continue with the write-only naming conventions
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  <fs3> = '|'.
ENDIF.
```